# How to select the range for pasting using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code for selecting the particular row and pasting it in column wise using paste-special property. It is working correctly my code is :

```
lngRow = Me.TextBox4.Value
strCol = Me.TextBox5.Value
Set rng = Range("A:A").Find(What:=lngRow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Value not found in row 1", vbExclamation
Else
 Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy
 Range("A1:E3").Columns(strCol).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
 Range("A1:E3").Rows(1).Copy
 Range("A1:E3").Columns(strCol).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
endif
```

the problem here is I am using
    Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy 
to copy the values
and for pasting I am using  Range("A1:E3").Columns(strCol).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True.

How can I paste all the values which are copied? Because if the values are in column F then this macro will not paste those values.

Comment: please explain you code in the else section more detailed, as what exactly you are trying to accomplish. I am guessing right now, that you want to copy a specific whole row, transposed to a column, into a different column - am I correct?

Comment: Ok, based on that, I gave you an answer. And just as a friendly reminder: it would be nice of you, to accept some of the answers to your question, if they helped you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will paste the whole row, if found, transposed to the given col, starting at row 1.

If it has to start at a different row or col, you should be able to adapt to that.

```
lngRow = Me.TextBox4.Value
strCol = Me.TextBox5.Value

Set rng = Range("A:A").Find(What:=lngRow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Value not found in row 1", vbExclamation
Else
 Range(Rng, Rng.End(xlToRight)).Copy
 Cells(1, strCol).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much But i want to paste the value into  columns(strcol).offset(,1).

Comment: Ok, no problem, so you just used `Columns(strCol).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True` istead of `Cells(1, strCol).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True` then.

Comment: hello can anybody tell me how to convert intger to chartcer in vba?.
i am using

    Chr(dest + 64)

but it is not showing the correct one
thanks in advance.